# Android: Bitmap scaling alternative

Tags: android, image-scaling, screen-size

I am currently writing an app in which my Bitmaps have to be (approximately) the same size in comparison to the screensize on all devices. So I just provided high res graphics and scaled them accordingly, but the result looks like trash (I scaled those Bitmaps by providing a srcRect and a smaller dstRect). 
The alternative solution would be to provide graphics for all screen sizes and densities, apart from beeing a pain in the ass, this would increase the size of my app tremendously. (I would have to provide resources for: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, large-mdpi, large-hdpi, large-xhdpi, xlarge-mdpi, xlarge-hdpi, xlarge-xhdpi).

So my question is: Is there another way to scale those Bitmaps, providing better results? Or is there any other (smarter) solution to this.

Thank you in advance! Wish you all a merry Christmas!

Comment: you should provide drawables for more screen sizes (not for all). Because small screen mean small amount of ram ("old" smartphones).

Comment: `providing better results` The best quality is given by providing pre-scaled bitmaps, as you are correctly doing. And it's also more efficient.

Comment: Upvote for merry christmas :) and supplying pre-scaled bitmaps is the most efficient way.You wont lose any time scaling images.

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) guides you through loading Bitmap files scaled to specific dimensions. Use that with the appropriate size based on the screen dimensions you need to support.